# How to use password hashing with salt in security.yml

Tags: symfony

I need random salt to hash password with users in file security.yml, not database. What i need to declare in "encoder" section to use salt in password hashing?

Comment: I think the phrase "random salt" might need some explanation. It sounds like if you're randomly generating the salt, you'll never be able to validate a password.


Are you generating a single random salt that's stored in security.yml and you want to use that against all passwords in your system?

Comment: no, it's randomly once - at generation. You can remove word "random" from my message if you want

Answer (score 0):

I think you shoud implement your own encoder logic by providing a service

```
services:
   custom_encoder:
       class: Acme\TestBundle\Service\CustomEncoder
```

It must implement Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\PasswordEncoderInterface

After that add this class to security.yml

```
security:
   encoders:
      Acme\TestBundle\Entity\User:
         id: custom_encoder
```